# Pushing elements externally to a reactive stream in fs2

Tags: scala, akka-stream, reactive-streams, fs2

I have an external (that is, I cannot change it) Java API which looks like this:

```java
public interface Sender {
    void send(Event e);
}
```

I need to implement a `Sender` which accepts each event, transforms it to a JSON object, collects some number of them into a single bundle and sends over HTTP to some endpoint. This all should be done asynchronously, without `send()` blocking the calling thread, with some fixed-size buffer and dropping new events if the buffer is full.

With akka-streams this is quite simple: I create a graph of stages (which uses akka-http to send HTTP requests), materialize it and use the materialized `ActorRef` to push new events to the stream:

```
lazy val eventPipeline = Source.actorRef[Event](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)
  .via(CustomBuffer(bufferSize))  // buffer all events
  .groupedWithin(batchSize, flushDuration)  // group events into chunks
  .map(toBundle)  // convert each chunk into a JSON message
  .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(sendHttpRequest)  // send an HTTP request
  .toMat(Sink.foreach { response =>
    // print HTTP response for debugging
  })(Keep.both)

lazy val (eventsActor, completeFuture) = eventPipeline.run()

override def send(e: Event): Unit = {
  eventsActor ! e
}
```

Here `CustomBuffer` is a custom `GraphStage` which is very similar to the library-provided `Buffer` but tailored to our specific needs; it probably does not matter for this particular question.

As you can see, interacting with the stream from non-stream code is very simple - the `!` method on the `ActorRef` trait is asynchronous and does not need any additional machinery to be called. Each event which is sent to the actor is then processed through the entire reactive pipeline. Moreover, because of how akka-http is implemented, I even get connection pooling for free, so no more than one connection is opened to the server.

However, I cannot find a way to do the same thing with FS2 properly. Even discarding the question of buffering (I will probably need to write a custom `Pipe` implementation which does additional things that we need) and HTTP connection pooling, I'm still stuck with a more basic thing - that is, how to push the data to the reactive stream "from outside".

All tutorials and documentation that I can find assume that the entire program happens inside some effect context, usually `IO`. This is not my case - the `send()` method is invoked by the Java library at unspecified times. Therefore, I just cannot keep everything inside one `IO` action, I necessarily have to finalize the "push" action inside the `send()` method, and have the reactive stream as a separate entity, because I want to aggregate events and hopefully pool HTTP connections (which I believe is naturally tied to the reactive stream).

I assume that I need some additional data structure, like `Queue`. fs2 does indeed have some kind of `fs2.concurrent.Queue`, but again, all documentation shows how to use it inside a single `IO` context, so I assume that doing something like

```
val queue: Queue[IO, Event] = Queue.unbounded[IO, Event].unsafeRunSync()
```

and then using `queue` inside the stream definition and then separately inside the `send()` method with further `unsafeRun` calls:

```
val eventPipeline = queue.dequeue
  .through(customBuffer(bufferSize))
  .groupWithin(batchSize, flushDuration)
  .map(toBundle)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(sendRequest)
  .evalTap(response => ...)
  .compile
  .drain

eventPipeline.unsafeRunAsync(...)  // or something

override def send(e: Event) {
  queue.enqueue(e).unsafeRunSync()
}
```

is not the correct way and most likely would not even work.

So, my question is, how do I properly use fs2 to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect._
import cats.effect.implicits._
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Answer {
  type Event = String

  trait Sender {
    def send(event: Event): Unit
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sender: Sender = {
      val ec = ExecutionContext.global
      implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ec)
      implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ec)

      fs2Sender[IO](2)
    }

    val events = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
    events.foreach { evt => new Thread(() => sender.send(evt)).start() }
    Thread sleep 3000
  }

  def fs2Sender[F[_]: Timer : ContextShift](maxBufferedSize: Int)(implicit F: ConcurrentEffect[F]): Sender = {
    // dummy impl
    // this is where the actual logic for batching
    //   and shipping over the network would live
    val consume: Pipe[F, Event, Unit] = _.evalMap { event =>
      for {
        _ <- F.delay { println(s"consuming [$event]...") }
        _ <- Timer[F].sleep(1.seconds)
        _ <- F.delay { println(s"...[$event] consumed") }
      } yield ()
    }

    val suspended = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[F, Event](maxBufferedSize)
      _ <- q.dequeue.through(consume).compile.drain.start
      sender <- F.delay[Sender] { evt =>
        val enqueue = for {
          wasEnqueued <- q.offer1(evt)
          _ <- F.delay { println(s"[$evt] enqueued? $wasEnqueued") }
        } yield ()
        enqueue.toIO.unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
      }
    } yield sender

    suspended.toIO.unsafeRunSync()
  }
}
```

The main idea is to use a concurrent Queue from fs2. Note, that the above code demonstrates that neither the `Sender` interface nor the logic in `main` can be changed. Only an implementation of the `Sender` interface can be swapped out.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing, and what I originally described in my question as something which I think won't work. It actually did work, so I believe this is indeed the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with exactly that library but it should look somehow like that:

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

case class Event(id: Int)

class JavaProducer{

  new Thread(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      var id = 0
      while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        id += 1
        send(Event(id))
      }
    }
  }).start()

  def send(event: Event): Unit ={
    println(s"Original producer prints $event")
  }
}

class HackedProducer(queue: Queue[IO, Event]) extends JavaProducer {
  override def send(event: Event): Unit = {
    println(s"Hacked producer pushes $event")
    queue.enqueue1(event).unsafeRunSync()
    println(s"Hacked producer pushes $event - Pushed")
  }

}

object Test extends IOApp{
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val x: IO[Unit] = for {
      queue <- Queue.unbounded[IO, Event]
      _ = new HackedProducer(queue)
      done <- queue.dequeue.map(ev => {
        println(s"Got $ev")
      }).compile.drain
    } yield done
    x.map(_ => ExitCode.Success)
  }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue I'm talking about - I don't have any producer to initialize inside a separate thread. The Java library I'm interfacing with is this producer, and I don't have any control over how it is instantiated.

Comment: Now I got your problem. Then your initial solution could possibly work if you don't call `unsafeRunAsync` after the initialization of the queue. Only when you push the element and in the end.

Comment: If I don't run `unsafeRunAsync` on `eventPipeline` (actually, in my current implementation I'll use `unsafeRunCancellable` because I need a way to shut this pipeline down due to the API requirements) then how the stream is going to start? Or if you meant not running `Queue.unbounded[..].unsafeRunSync()`, then how do I get the instance of the queue? Anyway, I'm currently in the process of trying it out.

Comment: Yes, I mean not running `Queue.unbounded[..].unsafeRunSync()`. Example is in my answer. Once you started `for` you are in the IO monad.

Comment: Then my situation is still not solved :) How do I get the instance of the `queue` inside the `send()` method in this case? If I would run `queue.unsafeRunSync()` inside `send()`, then I'll get a separate instance of `Queue` during each `send()` invocation, which wouldn't be connected in any way with the event pipeline.

Comment: `queue.enqueue(e).unsafeRunSync()` doesn't create a new queue. It just actually puts an element in this queue.

Comment: Yes, I know; but how do I get the `queue` instance in the first place? Either by running `queue.unsafeRunSync()` or by otherwise tying it into an IO action; regardless of how I do it, it still would be a new queue instance for each `send()` call.

Comment: In my example `queue <- Queue.unbounded[IO, Event]` the type of `queue` will be just `Queue`, not `IO[Queue]`. So you can pass it wherever you like. If it is still not clear I'll try to write a complete example but later.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a bounded queue that will consume elements from sender and make them available to fs2 stream processing.

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.std.Queue

import fs2.Stream

trait Sender[T]:
    def send(e: T): Unit

object Sender:
     def apply[T](bufferSize: Int): IO[(Sender[T], Stream[IO, T])] =
         for
             q <- Queue.bounded[IO, T](bufferSize)
         yield
             val sender: Sender[T] = (e: T) => q.offer(e).unsafeRunSync()
             def stm: Stream[IO, T] = Stream.eval(q.take) ++ stm
             (sender, stm)
```

Then we'll have two ends - one for Java worlds, to send new elements to `Sender`. Another one - for stream processing in fs2.

```
class TestSenderQueue:

    @Test def testSenderQueue: Unit =
        val (sender, stream) = Sender[Int](1)
          .unsafeRunSync()// we have to run it preliminary to make `sender` available to external system
        
        val processing = 
            stream
                .map(i => i * i)
                .evalMap{ ii => IO{ println(ii)}}
        sender.send(1)
                
        processing.compile.toList.start//NB! we start processing in a separate fiber
            .unsafeRunSync() // immediately right now.
        sender.send(2)
        Thread.sleep(100)
        (0 until 100).foreach(sender.send)
        println("finished")
```

Note that we push data in the current thread and have to run fs2 in a separate thread (`.start`).

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing, and what is described in the other answer, and what I originally described in my answer as something which I thought won't work :) but apparently it seems that is the correct way to do it, and it does work. Thanks anyway)